# Why is there memory leak by valgrind in a simple OCaml program?

Tags: memory-leaks, ocaml, valgrind

```ml
let main =
  print_endline "Hello world"
```

Here is a simple OCaml program ^

When I compile with `ocamlc`, and then run this program in valgrind:

```
==12457== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12457== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12457== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12457== Command: ./a.out
==12457== 
Hello world
==12457== 
==12457== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12457==     in use at exit: 7,391,113 bytes in 30 blocks
==12457==   total heap usage: 56 allocs, 26 frees, 7,470,447 bytes allocated
==12457== 
==12457== 256 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 15 of 27
==12457==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12457==    by 0x11D6BC: caml_stat_alloc (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457==    by 0x13627C: caml_executable_name (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457==    by 0x13C5C4: caml_main (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457==    by 0x11CDB1: main (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457== 
==12457== 3,936,288 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 27 of 27
==12457==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12457==    by 0x11D601: caml_alloc_for_heap (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457==    by 0x13EF42: caml_init_major_heap (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457==    by 0x12EFF5: caml_init_gc (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457==    by 0x13C43D: caml_main (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457==    by 0x11CDB1: main (in /usr/bin/ocamlrun)
==12457== 
==12457== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12457==    definitely lost: 256 bytes in 1 blocks
==12457==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12457==      possibly lost: 3,936,288 bytes in 1 blocks
==12457==    still reachable: 3,454,569 bytes in 28 blocks
==12457==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12457== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==12457== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==12457== 
==12457== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==12457== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

When I compile with `ocamlopt`, and then run this program in valgrind:

```
==12562== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12562== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12562== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12562== Command: ./a.out
==12562== 
Hello world
==12562== 
==12562== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12562==     in use at exit: 7,080,897 bytes in 27 blocks
==12562==   total heap usage: 27 allocs, 0 frees, 7,080,897 bytes allocated
==12562== 
==12562== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12562==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12562==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12562==      possibly lost: 3,936,288 bytes in 1 blocks
==12562==    still reachable: 3,144,609 bytes in 26 blocks
==12562==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12562== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==12562== 
==12562== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==12562== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Why is there memory leaks in the program compiled with `ocaml`? Are these just fake memory leaks? Do I have to worry about this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the OCaml GC is much wiser about what memory is acessible than an outside tool that doesn't know how OCaml works. Such tools need to make very general assumptions that can easily be wrong.

There are almost no leaks reported, just "possible" leaks (whatever that means). You could imagine the OCaml bytecode runtime allocates a small amount of global storage at startup. Calling this a "memory leak" is not correct, in my opinion. It would make no sense to release the memory at exit since this is just unnecessary work.

There is no leak shown for the native runtime (compiled with ocamlopt). So there doesn't seem to be anything that needs to be explained.

So, in sum, I wouldn't worry about this. It isn't an error so much as sensationalistic terminology in the output of the memory checker. If these were C programs there might be more reason to be concerned.

(However it still makes no sense to release global memory just before exit. Hence many C programs will report similar spurious "leaks" by this analysis.)

Answer (score 1):

The bytecode interpreter is "leaking" a 256 bytes string containing the executable name. Since the name is owned during the whole lifetime of the program, that does not really matter.

And since the "leak" is in the bytecode interpreter, it doesn't happen for the natively compiled program.

More generally using valgrind is not really useful for a garbage collected language (outside of compiler development), since the garbage collector will  gobble all memory. It is better to use a memory profiler that knows about the GC like statmemprof.